# How to use an abstract iterator (of the la4j library)?

Tags: java, iterator, abstract-class, libraries, la4j

It's a bit hard to phrase my question. I'm struggling a lot with using libraries in java currently and often are not really sure how to efficiently use them. In theory I know what an interface and an abstract class is but it seems that in practice these things are hard for me to use.
So, to be more specific, as an example, in the moment I'm using a CCS matrix from the la4j library. I now want to iterate over it (the rows and every entry in each of these rows) and want to use the library for it but I find only abstract iterators (e.g. the RowMajorMatrixIterator). In general: I don't know what to do with abstract classes (or interfaces) from libraries. Specifically in this moment and as a typical instance of my problem: If I have this abstract iterator, how do I actually use it (for my CCS Matrix)?
Every help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the iterators from the matrices you created beforehand: the class `Matrix` defines a method `rowMajorIterator()`, for example, so you can do

```
RowMajorMatrixIterator it = yourMatrix.rowMajorIterator();
```

This pattern is called "Factory Method".

As Thomas points out, it is often implemented as some sort of inner class, like this:

```
public class MyMatrix extends Matrix {
    public RowMajorIterator rowMajorIterator() {
        return new RowMajorIterator() { // anonymous class
            // needs to implement the abstract methods
            public int get() { ... } 
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
public class MyMatrix extends Matrix {
    public RowMajorIterator rowMajorIterator() {
        return new MyRowMajorIterator();
    }
    class MyRowMajorIterator extends RowMajorIterator { // inner, named class
        // needs to implement the abstract methods
        public int get() { ... } 
        ...
    }
}
```

These inner classes have access to the members of the "outer" class `Matrix`.

Comment: To expand on this: `rowMajorIterator()` will most likely return an instance of an anonymous subclass that extends `RowMajorIterator` (e.g. something like `new RowMajorIterator() { /* overriding or implementing methods here*/ }` (@daniu maybe you could put that into your answer and reformat/expand it a bit to help the OP get a better grasp of the concepts in general :) )

Comment: Thank you so much, I wasn't really aware of the factory method!
But this means I would still have to implement all methods of the iterator by myself?

Comment: @Autumn no the iterator the method gives you will have spring methods of course, Java doesn't allow to create instances of abstract classes.

Comment: Feel free to set this as the answer to your question using the checkmark ;)